# How do I create unique HTML titles in a python loop?

Tags: html, python-3.x, for-loop, url

I am trying to retrieve a few links that are changing, and then download them to my computer because we suspect the website will go down soon. My biggest problem is the name of the files are always the same. Is there a way the link names could change while still having .html at the end? Here is my code:

```
for contract_number in range(20):
    print(contract_number)
    for author_position in range(1,6):
        url = (insert link here).format(contract_number, author_position)
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        open('(name I want to change).html', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: I would think about using the `hash()` on the `insert link here` URL as the filename. Alternatively, you might do some `replace()` work on the URL to make it a valid filename

Comment: Alternatively, it looks like files are based on contract and author so you might use a filename of `f"{contract_number }_{author_position}.html"`